# Azure does not override application settings

Tags: azure, connection-string, azure-web-app-service, application-settings

In my Azure App Service I want to update application settings, but after publish from VS the keys doesn't override values from local Web.config

In Azure it looks like:
[image]

In the result my web.config on azure contains values from local settings

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MainConnectionString" connectionString="ConnectionStringToReplaceByAzure" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="MS_SigningKey" value="Overridden by portal settings" />
  </appSettings>
```

Comment: Does this work with an edmx file? Did you ever get this working? I am struggling also. Do I include the Quotes around the connectionString? do I include the providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" in the connString on Azure? #FrustratedIncorporated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Azure never physically modifies your web.config file. Instead, the Azure App Setting is injected into the config system at runtime. So even though you don't see it in web.config, if you query it from your app you will get the correct value.