# Azure application settings, does not reflect on NodeJs app

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service, appsettings, kudu

**I understood** from 2 answers in SO, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35870476/28004) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45369398/28004), that even if we update the Application Settings, the current portal UI does not reflect those changes, **but** that if we read through our application, we would get the updated settings...

That is not happening in my NodeJs application for some odd reason:

as a [Bitbucket pipeline](https://bitbucket.org/product/features/pipelines) step, I get the last committed hash and using the Kudo REST API, I update my application setting, and that works fine as seen in the Kudo settings:

[image]

The bad is that when requesting such variable through `process.env.SOURCE_VERSION` I get the `string` that is in the portal GUI and not this one:

[image]

and that, in HTML translates to:

[image]

that **123** string is exactly what is in the portal GUI

[image]

From the answers I've found, it must be something I'm forgetting ... but I've been stuck on this for some time and I can't figure it out what am I missing :(

---

As a **very weird test**, I've updated the portal GUI to `1234` and, even Kudo settings still show the git commit hash, in the HTML page I now get `1234`.

So it's definitely showing changes, but not what I dynamically update, just the portal variables :/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This was discussed on [`KUDU REST POST /api/settings won't work how it supposed to? #283`](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/283). As @ahmelsayed said that settings API `*.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/settings` is not the same as what you get from /Env.

You have two options to ensure the consistency of app settings.

- [Set settings through Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/config/appsettings?view=azure-cli-latest), then get settings through `process.env['xxx']` in your Node.js application.
- Set settings by doing a POST to `*.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/settings`, then get settings by doing a GET to `*.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/settings` in your Node.js appliction.